# Removing backbone views but DOM node count keeps going up?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-management, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

I have a quiz application built in backboneJS, I have three views.  A QuizView which shows the overall progress and back/next buttons.  A PageView that contains a group of questions and a QuestionView for each question.

When a user goes to the next page in a quiz I remove the current PageView by calling a destroy function that calls Backbone's remove() on the page itself and all the questions. (all listeners are attached with listenTo)

It's my expectation that after I do this that DOM nodes should not longer be reflected in memory timeline.  I've attached a view of the DOM node count from Chrome dev tools and you can see it goes up as you go to new pages.

I also took a heap snapshot and when I look at the detached DOM items they all have one item (the div container for a page) that has a single item in the retaining tree. I'm assuming this is why they are not being collected.

Can anyone provide insight at to why the DOM node count continuously goes up?

Also this is my destroy function in PageView:

```
destroy: function(){
    console.log("PageView :: destroy " + this)
    _.each(this.childViews, function(view){
        view.remove();
    });

    this.remove();
}
```

[image: Timeline View]
[image: Heap Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have any reference between your objects they won't be eligible for garbage collection. These views are the "Zombie views". How to deal with such cases is perfectly explained in this post:

[Zombies! RUN! (Managing Page Transitions In Backbone Apps)](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

---

By

> **view.remove()**  Removes a view from the DOM, and calls stopListening to
>   remove any bound events that the view has listenTo'd.

you basically removed the `events: {}` and the DOM for that view. However, events listening on `trigger` and model events like

```
this.model.on('reset', this.render, this)
```

are still alive and holding reference to your view, making it ineligible for garbage collection.

Comment: this makes sense, however in my case I do not use "on" or "trigger" for any events so I thought the default remove function should be enough.

Comment: if you have any listenTo in your view/collection/model, it's best to opt for 'this.model.off(null, null, this)' or 'this.collection.off(null, null, this)'

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into the same issue. **When recording in chrome dev tools the garbage collector is prevented from running.** You must must run it manually by clicking the GC button.

[image: Dev Tools GC Button]

I built [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufre0nyz/1/) to create nodes, then delete them all when 10 were created. Thinking that node count should reset when they were removed from the dom. It did not. Then I noticed the GC button at the top...

Guess you can inject demos right into SO now. No need for a fiddle. That's cool...

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var stuff = document.getElementById("stuff");

test.addEventListener("click", testFn);

var count = 0;

function testFn(){
    
    console.log('create '+count);
    
    // create a new div element 
    // and give it some content 
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("test "+count); 
    count++;
    
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 
    
    stuff.appendChild(newDiv);
    
    if(count == 10){
        
        while (stuff.firstChild) {
            stuff.removeChild(stuff.firstChild);
        }   
        
        count = 0;
        
    } 
    
};
```

```html
<div id="test">page should start with 14 nodes. click me.</div>
<div id="stuff">&nbsp;</div>
```